# Where to include stargazer table resizing?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am using `stargazer` to produce gorgeous tables. My issue is that I want to resize the table to something like `{0.8\textwidth}`. But I don't understand stargazor's table layout, and am unsure where to include it.

Here is the first chunk of the table:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]

\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lD{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} D{.}{.}{-2} }

\\[-1.8ex]\hline

\hline \\[-1.8ex]

& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\

\cline{2-6}

\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{5}{c}{DA} \\

\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{probit}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{generalized linear}} \\

& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{mixed-effects}} \\

\\[-1.8ex] & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}\\

\hline \\[-1.8ex]

Constant & -0.54^{***} & -0.54^{***} & -0.54^{***} & -0.54^{***} & -0.54^{***} \\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm afraid I'm not familiar with stargazer. LaTeX and some external packages -- specifically, `dcolumn` and `booktabs` -- let you create plenty-good-looking tables on their own.

To achieve an overall width of `0.8\textwidth`, I suggest you employ a `tabular*` environment and set its overall width to `0.8\textwidth`.

The framelines at the edges of the following screenshot are drawn courtesy of the `showframe` package; don't load the package in the final production run.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable class

\usepackage{dcolumn}    % for 'D' column type
\usepackage{booktabs}   % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{showframe}  % draw framelines around textblock (optional)
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out intercolumn whitespace amount
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{5}{d{2.5}} }
\toprule
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\
& \multicolumn{5}{c}{DA} \\
\cmidrule{2-6}
& \mc{\textit{probit}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textit{generalized linear mixed-effects}} \\
\cmidrule{2-2} \cmidrule{3-6}
         & \mc{(1)}    & \mc{(2)}    & \mc{(3)}    & \mc{(4)}    & \mc{(5)}    \\
\midrule
Constant & -0.54^{***} & -0.54^{***} & -0.54^{***} & -0.54^{***} & -0.54^{***} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you what these lines of code do? `\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}`,`\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}`, and `l *{5}{d{2.5}}`?

Comment: @Adam_G - The first instruction creates a new column type, called `d`, on the basis of the `D` column type that's provided by the `dcolumn` package. The second creates a macro called `\mc`, which takes one argument. The third says that the table layout contains 6 columns overall: one of type `l`, followied by 5 columns of type `d`. May I suggest you peruse the user guide of the `dcolumn` package to learn more about the `D` column type?

Comment: Thanks! Will do. Stargazer just had me import the dcolumn package but made no mention of what it is for/what is does.